# What is the difference between these two lambda functions in Python?

Tags: python

In the following python code, both lambda functions return the same value, which is x:

```
x = [2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8]
print(lambda x: x == 2)

print(lambda x: x if x == 2 else None)
```

From my understanding, the first lambda function is also an if statement, but I don't quite understand its syntax.

Comment: Why print the lambda?

Comment: They don’t both return the same value, but it’s harder to tell that if you don’t call them.

Comment: The first returns `True` or `False`, the second returns `x` or `None`.

Answer (score 1):

The first will return a boolean value (`True` or `False`), whereas the second one will return either `2` or `None` depending on if `x == 2` or not.

The first is the same as the following code:

```
def f(x):
    return (x == 2) # returns either True or False
```

But the second is the same as this code:

```
def f(x):
    if (x == 2):
        return (x) 
        # if the code takes this path, x will always be 2 when it's returned
    else:
        return (None) 
        # None is not the same as false
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095654/what-is-a-nonetype-object) for the difference between `None` and `False`

Comment: those parentheses are redundant

Comment: @Matiiss they are redundant, but I left them in the code for clarity since the long form (non lambda) code is intended to be as readable as possible

Comment: why don't you do `return (x)` and `return (None)` then?  they are redundant, they don't help with readability or clarity, they are annoying imo, `if` or `return` is not a function, you don't call it, adding parentheses to a name in Python means calling it, it doesn't happen here because those are keywords

Comment: @Matiiss I've edited to include `return (x)` and `return (none)`. Have a nice day.

Comment: that's redundancy, redundancy in fact does not help with readability

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442088/what-are-some-examples-of-where-using-parentheses-in-a-program-lowers-readabilit/2442151#2442151) about how using parenthesis can help novice readers of python understand the flow of the code